# Unity3d get Mouse Input Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

I want to rotate a GameObject through mouse movement between -20° and +20°.

I know that there's a possibility to grab the smoothed Input through 
`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` and `Input.GetAxis("Vertical");` which returns float values between `-1` and `1`

It would be nice if there would exist something like 
`Input.GetMouseAxis("Horizontal");` or `Input.GetMouseAxis("Horizontal");`.

But I the output shouldn't be influenced by keyboard.
I'm sorry that I don't have much experience  with Unity and its API.

Comment: Have you tried Input.GetAxisRaw() http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html

Comment: You could also try Input.MousePosition() http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html

Comment: is the mouse in unity "captured" in screen resolution or how should I scale the mouse Position to a value between -1 and 1 ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it is, as you say, captured inside the resolution, try Debug.Log(Input.MousePosition()); to see what comes up, same with getaxisraw. (Sorry if you already new to do this).

Comment: >the raw's don't change on mouse move
>the mouseposition seems to be a bit strange-in the upper left corner is [0,480] and not like in winforms [0,0] :/ , but the values could get negative in not-fullscreenmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the mouse in unity "captured" in screen resolution or how should I
>   scale the mouse Position to a value between -1 and 1 ?

In this case the "normalizedSpeed" will be your target

```
public float mouseDistance;
public Vector2 mouseDown = -Vector2.one;

public float normalizedSpeed;

public void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      mouseDown = Input.MousePosition();

   if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
      mouseDown = -Vector2.one;

   if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
      normalizedSpeed = mouseDown != -Vector2.one ?
      Mathf.Clamp((mouseDown - Input.MousePosition()).sqrMagnitude, 0, (mouseDistance * mouseDistance)) / (mouseDistance * mouseDistance)
      : 0;
}
```

i use sqrMagnitude instead of distance because the sqr root call in distance() takes alot of memory, so it is faster to compare the squared distances vs each other

Also keep in mind im wirting this as a pseudo-code so the overall idea is what im going for, im leaving you syntactically responsible for the implementation ;)